# Прерывается работа couroutine (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Пишу Space Shooter. В скрипте Gamecontroller есть couroutine, отвечающий за респавн противников.

```
IEnumerator SpawnEnemies() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBeforeSpawning);
    while(true) {
        if (currentNumberOfEnemies <= 1) {
            waveNumber++;
            waveText.text = "Волна: " + waveNumber;
            float randDirection;
            float randDistance;
            for (int i = 0; i < enemiesPerWave; i++) {
                randDistance = Random.Range (10, 25);
                randDirection = Random.Range (0, 360);
                float posX = this.transform.position.x + (Mathf.Cos ((randDirection) * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * randDistance);
                float posY = this.transform.position.y + (Mathf.Cos ((randDirection) * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * randDistance);
                Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(posX, posY, 0), this.transform.rotation);
                currentNumberOfEnemies++;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenEnemies);
            }
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (timeBeforeWaves); 
    }   
}
```

В другом скрипте, который контролирует игрока, есть строчка, останавливающая выполнение couroutine, когда у игрока заканчиваются очки здоровья.

```
if (hp == 0)
{
    GameOverText.enabled = true;
    GameController gameController = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController").GetComponent("GameController") as GameController;
    gameController.StopAllCoroutines();
}
```

В случае, если всех противников в волне убивает лазер (стандартный сценарий их смерти), все идет хорошо. Но если хотя бы один противник разбивается об игрока, независимо от количества здоровья игрока, спавн противников прекращается.
Подскажите, плиз, куда копать?

Comment: Самое простое это взять отладчик и подебажить в тот момент, когда `противник разбивается об игрока`.... Потому что причин на данный момент может быть масса и причем не в предоставленном коде....... может быть где-то в переменные попадают значения и в результате условия внутри корутины не отрабатывают..... может быть где-то еще стоит триггер/событие за счет которого выключается корутина,....а может где-то стоит условие и происходит вообще `Destroy(Gamecontroller)` или `Disable(Gamecontroller)`

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема и правда была чуть-чуть в стороне от приложенного мной кода. Я забыл при смерти противника от столкновения с игроком открутить счетчик количества противников. В результате момент респавна не мог наступить из-за того, что соответствующая корутина считала, что их больше, чем на самом деле было на экране =)

Comment: `AlexeyShimanskyTelepatLevel += 1;`  :D